# Piping module scanning all unrelated files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, pipe

My application was running fine until last week when I start running it in development mode (webpack hot development) as usual; It starts scanning files that have never changed and kept reloading the project. Recently, it got even worse - start crawling into my `node_modules` folder and reloading by each file, and eventually crashed.

It has never happened before until recently, and I have no idea what caused it to behave like that suddenly.

**command prompt logs**

```
[1]   Initial data loaded, starting server...                                                                                                            
[1] ----                                                                                                                                                   
[1] ==> ✅  Portal is running, talking to API server at http://localhost:3335.                                                                   
[1] ==>   Open http://localhost:3000 in a browser to view the app.                                                                                       
[0] webpack building...                                                                                                                                    
[1] [piping] File src\constants.js has changed, reloading.                                                                                                 
[1] [piping] File src\components\Dialog\Dialog.js has changed, reloading.                                                                                  
[1] internal/process.js:183                                                                                                                                
[1]       throw util._errnoException(err, 'kill');                                                                                                         
[1]       ^                                                                                                                                                
[1]                                                                                                                                                        
[1] Error: kill ESRCH                                                                                                                                      
[1]     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)                                                                                                        
[1]     at process.kill (internal/process.js:183:18)                                                                                                       
[1]     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\portal\node_modules\piping\lib\piping.js:87:19)                                 
[1]     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)                                                                                                                      
[1]     at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:214:7)                                                                                                                
[1]     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\portal\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:196:15)                                   
[1]     at FSWatcher._emit (C:\Users\user\Documents\portal\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:238:5)                                          
[1]     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\portal\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:263:16)                      
[1]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)                                                                                                              
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                               
[1] npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                       
[1] npm ERR! portal@0.1.0 start-dev: `better-npm-run start-dev`                                                                                     
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                 
[1] npm ERR!                                                                                                                                               
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the portal@0.1.0 start-dev script.                                                                                           
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                     
[1]                                                                                                                                                        
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                   
[1] npm ERR!     C:\Users\mok\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-21T01_10_39_440Z-debug.log                                                   
[1] npm run start-dev exited with code 1                                                                                                                   
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..                                                                                                                   
[2] gulp watch --gulpfile semantic/gulpfile.js exited with code 1                                                                                          
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                               
[0] npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                       
[0] npm ERR! portal@0.1.0 watch-client: `better-npm-run watch-client`                                                                               
[0] npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                 
[0] npm ERR!                                                                                                                                               
[0] npm ERR! Failed at the portal@0.1.0 watch-client script.                                                                                        
[0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                     
[0] npm run watch-client exited with code 1                                                                                                                
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                                   
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                           
npm ERR! portal@0.1.0 dev: `concurrently --kill-others "npm run watch-client" "npm run start-dev" "gulp watch --gulpfile semantic/gulpfile.js"`     
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                     
npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                   
npm ERR! Failed at the portal@0.1.0 dev script.                                                                                                     
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                         

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                       
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-21T01_10_40_197Z-debug.log
```

After reading a few related issues on the GitHub

- https://github.com/mdlawson/piping/issues/10
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4852
- https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/638

I realized updating the `piping` module version to `^1.0.0-rc.1` or above *should* fix the problem.

TL;DR

However, the next day I ran it again, it starts showing me the similar behavior again, but it didn't crash my command prompt when starting, only worse: when I start changing a code or a file, it would go into my `node_modules` and reload ten or hundred times:

**command prompt logs (when I change a file)**

```
[0] webpack built e36ced9f06f9f77a7631 in 1203ms
[0] webpack building...
[1] [piping] File node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDOM.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDOMFeatureFlags.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_parent.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\flatten.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\now.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_basePickBy.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_asciiSize.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_unicodeSize.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_arrayAggregator.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_baseAggregator.js has changed, reloading.
// more
```

**command prompt logs (when starting in dev-mode)**

```
[1] Executing script: start-dev
[1]
[0] Executing script: watch-client
[0]
[1] to be executed: "node ./bin/server.js"
[0] to be executed: "node webpack/webpack-dev-server.js"
[2] [15:24:29] Working directory changed to ~\Documents\portal\semantic
[1] [piping] File node_modules\core-js\library\modules\web.immediate.js has changed, reloading.
[0] ==>   Webpack development server listening on port 3001
[1] [piping] File node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes\lib\loose.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\babel-helper-remap-async-to-generator\lib\for-await.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\react\lib\React.js has changed, reloading.
[2] [15:24:45] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\htm-owner-portal\semantic\gulpfile.js
[2] [15:24:45] Starting 'watch'...
[2] Watching source files for changes
[1] [piping] File node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactComponentBrowserEnvironment.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\react-dom\lib\getEventCharCode.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_arrayMap.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File bin\server.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\webpack-isomorphic-tools\babel-transpiled-modules\tools\log.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\react\lib\React.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\Parser.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\domutils\lib\traversal.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\react-router\lib\PromiseUtils.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\redux-actions\lib\handleActions.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\formidable\lib\multipart_parser.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\semantic-ui-react\dist\commonjs\lib\classNameBuilders.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\semantic-ui-react\dist\commonjs\elements\Label\LabelDetail.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\lodash\_baseInRange.js has changed, reloading.
[1] [piping] File node_modules\airbnb-prop-types\build\componentWithName.js has changed, reloading.
```

This is my `piping` module version (please let me know if you need any more information):

**npm-shrinkwrap.json**

```
"piping": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/piping/-/piping-1.0.0-rc.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-d1oUz2UapC7ltKrKs1SMUXShXw=",
  "requires": {
    "chokidar": "1.7.0",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.10"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

`"piping": "^1.0.0-rc.4",`

**webpack development config**

```
require('babel-polyfill');

// Webpack config for development
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/dist');
var host = (process.env.HOST || 'localhost');
var port = (+process.env.PORT + 1) || 3001;

// https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools
var WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = require('webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin');
var webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = new WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin(require('./webpack-isomorphic-tools'));

var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc');
var babelrcObject = {};

try {
  babelrcObject = JSON.parse(babelrc);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('==>     ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.');
  console.error(err);
}


var babelrcObjectDevelopment = babelrcObject.env && babelrcObject.env.development || {};

// merge global and dev-only plugins
var combinedPlugins = babelrcObject.plugins || [];
combinedPlugins = combinedPlugins.concat(babelrcObjectDevelopment.plugins);

var babelLoaderQuery = Object.assign({}, babelrcObjectDevelopment, babelrcObject, {plugins: combinedPlugins});
delete babelLoaderQuery.env;

// Since we use .babelrc for client and server, and we don't want HMR enabled on the server, we have to add
// the babel plugin react-transform-hmr manually here.

// make sure react-transform is enabled
babelLoaderQuery.plugins = babelLoaderQuery.plugins || [];
var reactTransform = null;
for (var i = 0; i < babelLoaderQuery.plugins.length; ++i) {
  var plugin = babelLoaderQuery.plugins[i];
  if (Array.isArray(plugin) && plugin[0] === 'react-transform') {
    reactTransform = plugin;
  }
}

if (!reactTransform) {
  reactTransform = ['react-transform', {transforms: []}];
  babelLoaderQuery.plugins.push(reactTransform);
}

if (!reactTransform[1] || !reactTransform[1].transforms) {
  reactTransform[1] = Object.assign({}, reactTransform[1], {transforms: []});
}

// make sure react-transform-hmr is enabled
reactTransform[1].transforms.push({
  transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
  imports: ['react'],
  locals: ['module']
});

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
    'main': [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://' + host + ':' + port + '/__webpack_hmr',
      'font-awesome-webpack!./src/theme/font-awesome.config.js',
      './src/client.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: 'http://' + host + ':' + port + '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery), 'eslint-loader']},
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.css/, loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version' },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }
    ]
  },
  progress: true,
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    // hot reload
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats\.json$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
      __DEVTOOLS__: true
    }),
    webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.development()
  ]
};
```

Anyone else is facing this issue or anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please supply at least your webpack config and your gulpfile, better yet provide a minimum example repo somewhere that reproduces the error.

Comment: Just added the webpack config code in, hope it helps! I don't think I can reproduce this error, I'm currently working in a development team of 3 and so far only 2 of us got this error (me first, then the other developer too) and the other developer still working fine; And this behaviour also spread to my other projects that use the same config, so I have really no clue if it is node or computer or the code that has the problem.

Comment: where and why does webpack use piping? I am assuming, all devs run the exact same version of `node`, `npm` and share the same repo/branch that you do, and that you ran `rimraf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i ` so make sure it is no cache issue

Comment: However, a MWE would be highly appreciated. Additionally: try to get a vm, clean install `node` and the repo and see if the issue persists. If yes, the issue is externous (libs, node, code) if no, there is something with your (and your collegues) environment. BTW: often if I try to create a MWE, it works and the issue was caused by some injection'sh stuff

Comment: @Joel I guess `rimraf node_modules package-lock.json` is equivalent to `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`? I'll try to run it and let you know if it fixes the issue. Btw, what is MWE?

Comment: yes, it is the same but `rimraf` mitigates (at least) path-to-long issues under windows. MWE stands for minimal working example. something, that you can share and we can have a certain look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method that works so far for me is: Reformat the computer.

My assumption is that it was related to the conflict process with other programmes in my computer (saw error regarding PID - process identifier in the logs).

I decided to reformat my computer and reclone it to test it out; now the error doesn't show up anymore and the piping works great again.